# find ID of parent DIV and fade DIV out

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im trying to fade out a DIV when clicking a link within the DIV itself. Here is my code:

```
$(".hideinfo").click(function () {
  var parentLink = $(this).parent().parent();               
  $(parentLink).fadeTo("slow", 0);
});
```

The reason I'm not specifying the ID directly is because I want to use this to fade out multiple DIVs with different ID's.

The above code was returning the ID when I setup an alert but not fading the DIV out or anything else I tried to so... any help here would be appreciated. The HTML is:

```
<div id="First-Block" class="item">                 
    <p>text here</p>
    <p><a href="#" class="hideinfo">Back</a></p>    
</div>
```

Thank you!

Comment: The code works. The problem is not there. I forgot to add unless you are having problems with cross-browser opacity setting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `fadeOut("slow")` instead.

Try changing your code to:

```
$(".hideinfo").click(function () {
    var parentLink = $(this).parent().parent();
    $(parentLink).fadeOut("slow");
});
```

To improve this even further you can shorten your code to:

```
$(".hideinfo").click(function() {
    $(this).closest(".item").fadeOut("slow");
});
```

Just to mention as well that by clicking on an anchor it will jump to the top of the page using `#`. I would take a look at [.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

You can also check out the API here -> http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/

Comment: Thank you Sam, that works a charm. I had some confusion over the roles of fadeTo and FadeOut. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/otoker/edit#javascript,html,live)*

```
$(".hideinfo").click(function( e ){
    e.preventDefault();           // prevent default anchor link behavior
    $(this).closest('.item').fadeTo(400, 0);
});
```

Additionally try to wrap the above into a `document ready` :

```
$(function(){
   // code here.
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [fadeOut()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) instead since your primary goal is to affect the overall visibiltity not a given opacity.